# "Failed to execute child process child process 'software-properties-gtk' (No such file or directory)" happened

Tags: python, ubuntu, debugging, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

A lot of errors occur in my Ubuntu18.04.I can't open some applications in my activity, such as 'terminal' and 'software and update'. When I am trying to click the logo of 'software and update', "Failed to execute child process child process 'software-properties-gtk' (No such file or directory)" jumped out.It is OK to open a terminal in a directory but failed by tapping the logo. But if open by tapping logo, "Failed to execute child process child process 'gnome-terminal' (No such file or directory)" happened.I do not know why and ask for help.More error details will provided if you ask me.Hope for a favor and thanks a lot.
Adding, this error happened in a server and after a restart.Before the restart I installed Matlab on it.Maybe this information would help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add pictures? The text is really compressed and hard to read.

Comment: I edit again, some advice?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libSDL2-2.0` Found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/916282/failed-to-execute-child-process-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Sorry, It didn't work.